# Add Custom Grid into a Custom Tab in Product Edit Page collection filter by current product id

Tags: magento2, product, grid, tabs

As per my requirement, I need to add a custom grid into a custom tab in the product edit page.

for that, I got one of the good tutorials, but in that, I need to filter the collection by the current product id.

http://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-add-custom-grid-into-a-custom-tab-in-product-edit-page-in-magento-2-admin/

But right now the grid gets the full collection of the custom model.

In that how can I achieve the filter using the current product id?

Updated code in
**custom_grid_listing.xml**

```
<dataSource name="questionanswer_grid_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="product_id" xsi:type="string">*</item>
            </item>
            <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>

            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cacheRequests" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

**CustomDataProvider.php**

Then i am using below code go get the product_id from the URL, but in URL dont have any product realated infromation

```
$params =  $this->_request->getParams();
$urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
echo $urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($params);
```

[image]

Kindly check the details and share your knowledge.

Thanks in advance for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code snippet inside **custom_grid_listing_data_source** tag under settings:

> **app/code/Codextblog/Customgridtab/view/adminhtml/ui_component/custom_grid_listing.xml**

```
<filterUrlParams>
    <param name="product_id">*</param>
</filterUrlParams>
```

Looks like:

```
<dataSource name="custom_grid_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
    <settings>
        <filterUrlParams>
            <param name="product_id">*</param>
        </filterUrlParams>
        <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
    </settings>
    ........
</dataSource>
```

In that case, your new table should **product_id** column exists, otherwise will throw an exception.

Comment: thanks for your comments, i followed as per your way, but still i didn't get the product_id from the URL parameter, i updated my question with the code and response screen. Kindly check and share your thoughts

Comment: Can you add your module somewhere with db table will easy fix.

Comment: i can not able to share the module to any where, apart from that do you need any other details i can

Comment: Hi @senthil, were you able to get past this issue? I'm currently experiencing this exact issue..

Comment: @senthil Did you solve this issue?

Comment: I solved the issue and add that as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the below in Ui/DataProvider/Product/CustomDataProvider.php

```
$this->getCollection()->addEntityFilter($this->request->getParam('current_product_id', 0));
```

and in Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomTab.php

```
            'imports' => [
                                'productId' => '${ $.provider }:data.product.current_product_id',
                                '__disableTmpl' => ['productId' => false],
                            ],
                            'exports' => [
                                'productId' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.current_product_id',
                                '__disableTmpl' => ['productId' => false],
                            ],
```

You can compare the module with vendor/magento/module-review module. It has similar functionality